How do I link headings containing spaces in Markdown?
I am working on a knowledgebase where I interlink documents using hyperlinks of file names and their associated headings.
For example:
Compatibility in !Sidebar with [Compatibility](Compatibility). I can also link specific headings from within other files like so: [Compatibility](Compatibility#Titles) which opens Compatibility.md @ ## Titles.
However, if a heading contains spaces, I cannot seem to link them. Is it possible to hyperlink headings containing spaces in Markdown?
I would prefer to keep the spaces I have with many of the headings I already have in place.

Note that in general fragment links don't work in Markdown hosted directly in github (in the repository preview, rather than a GitHub Pages site), because it injects user-content- prefixes inconsistently.


“Is it possible to hyperlink a heading containing spaces in Markdown?”

Yes! Just use the URL percent encoding equivalent for a space (aka: %20) instead of a space on the link. For example, if you wanted to link to Long Titles, instead of this:
[Compatibility](Compatibility#Long Titles)

You would do this:
[Compatibility](Compatibility#Long%20Titles)

Just be sure the heading actually has an id= that is actually set to Long Titles.

Markdown doesn't know that you're linking to a Markdown heading – all it knows is that you're linking to some other HTML page. Meaning that it's not the actual heading text but the rendered HTML tags that matter.
Markdown renderers typically replace spaces with dashes when generating anchors. A heading like "System Requirements" would usually have the anchor #system-requirements. Additionally, most special characters tend to be removed.
If the target page is on GitHub, you can use the 'link' icon that appears when hovering on a heading to see where it links (it links to itself, and its purpose is to let you copy a link to the heading). Right-click it, select "Copy link target", paste the result into your document and trim down the unwanted parts.
In most other cases (i.e. not on GitHub, which uses fancy JS to handle #fragment links), you can right-click a heading and use the browser's "Inspect" option to see what <h2 id= or <a name= was generated. For example, there may be a <h2 id="sysreq">System requirements</h2> which is linked as #sysreq.

URIs are not permitted to contain spaces.  This is as true of the fragment identifier portion as it is of the hostname and path.
For characters not permitted in URIs, we must use the hexadecimal representation - in this case %20 as space is represented as 0x20 in UTF-8.
